# Listen for XDebug php in vscode with xampp

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp

Once I performed all the configuration stuff, downliading the .dll, adding it to the ext path in xamp and to the php.ini etc.

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9003
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

After adding both configs in vsCode:

1.- Installing the php debug extension
2.- Run->AddConfiguration->Listen for Xdebug
3.- Run->AddConfiguration->"Launch currently open script"

So both debug modes seem to be possible:

[image]

Surprisingly I can make the debug work if I "Launch currently open script".
De default config for the "Launch currently open script" is:

```
{
    "name": "Launch currently open script",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
    "port": 0,
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
    ],
    "env": {
        "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
        "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
    },
}
```

But that did not work until I added `runtimeExecutable":"C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe`.

For the case 1.- Listen for Xdebug, that is to debug the whole app without the need of selecting an specific file, I could not make it work. The launch.json is:

```
{
    "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9003
}
```

I tried of course adding the `runtimeExecutable":"C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe`, changing the ports, restarting apache and vs code and adding to de vs code settings the  Allow Breakpoints Everywhere checkbox.

I am close, because for **Launch current script** mode works but when I launch vscode with the **Listen for Xdebug** option, my breakpoints are in place and my page is reloaded for check. Nothing happens and there are no errors in the vscode debug console.

Any idea of what needs to be done for the Listen for Xdebug to work and be able to debug the whole proyect with vscode?

Edit:

I also tried adding this options to my php.ini:

```
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047656/xdebug-not-working-in-vscode-for-php-debugging)

and the visualStudio php configuration Listen for XDebug 2 (Legacy)

[image]

Followed the intructions from the extension [docs](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug) and I dont find what is wrong.

Comment: Just why u don't use docker?

Comment: not familiar with it. Instead of what? The php debug extension you mean?

Comment: instead this piece of not good code "XAMPP" - in docker Xdebug and other things works as at real servers. XAMPP good only for novices hwo just came in IT - but they don't know what is Xdebug :)

Comment: just my case, not new to IT but yes to php :)

Comment: Nice! Than move XAMPP to trash and start with Docker! Really, with XAMPP you waste your time.

Comment: Good, question! Looking for an answer, also. This [blog](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/php-debug/), however, recommends `Launch currently open script`